# Feynman diagram alignment with equal sign

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-feynman, feynman

Literally what the question's title is, I am having trouble with aligning three Feynman diagrams. Here is my code:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}
\begin{equation}
\feynmandiagram[horizontal=a to b, layered layout]{
a[particle = \(\mu\nu\)] --[photon] b [blob]
};
=
\feynmandiagram[horizontal=a to b, layered layout]{
a[particle = \(\mu\nu\)] --[photon] b [dot]
}; 
+
\feynmandiagram[horizontal=a to b, layered layout]{
a[particle = \(\mu\nu\)] --[photon] b [dot],
b -- [scalar, reversed momentum'=\(\ell\), loop, min distance=2.5cm,rotate = -90] b,
};
\end{equation}
```

with a lot of packages loaded, hence you don't see the "begin document" commands or anything (but I included the relevant packages).
[image: weird alignment]
Here is the rendered image of the code above:

I also was wondering if there was anyway to make the last tadpole diagram more circular, and smaller as well.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions or help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `inline=(a.base)`, but you also need to fix the bounding box with `\strut`.

Also some additional spacing around the operation or relation symbols is useful.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \feynmandiagram[inline=(a.base),horizontal=a to b, layered layout]{%
  a[particle = \strut\(\mu\nu\)] -- [photon] b [blob]
  };
\;=
  \feynmandiagram[inline=(a.base),horizontal=a to b, layered layout]{%
  a[particle = \strut\(\mu\nu\)] -- [photon] b [dot]
  };
\;+
  \feynmandiagram[inline=(a.base),horizontal=a to b, layered layout]{%
  a[particle = \strut\(\mu\nu\)] --[photon] b [dot],
  b -- [scalar, reversed momentum'=\(\ell\), loop, 
        min distance=2.5cm,rotate = -90] b,
  };
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you encase all three diagrams in `\vcenter{\hbox{...}}` primitives.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\vcenter{\hbox{%
  \feynmandiagram[horizontal=a to b, layered layout]{%
  a[particle = \(\mu\nu\)] --[photon] b [blob]
  };}}
=
\vcenter{\hbox{%
  \feynmandiagram[horizontal=a to b, layered layout]{%
  a[particle = \(\mu\nu\)] --[photon] b [dot]
  };}}
+
\vcenter{\hbox{%
  \feynmandiagram[horizontal=a to b, layered layout]{%
  a[particle = \(\mu\nu\)] --[photon] b [dot],
  b -- [scalar, reversed momentum'=\(\ell\), loop, 
        min distance=2.5cm,rotate = -90] b,
  };}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[preview, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\feynmandiagram[horizontal=a to b, layered layout, baseline]{
a[particle = \(\mu\nu\)] --[photon] b [blob]
};
\quad=\quad
\feynmandiagram[horizontal=a to b, layered layout, baseline]{
a[particle = \(\mu\nu\)] --[photon] b [dot]
}; 
\quad+\quad
\feynmandiagram[horizontal=a to b, layered layout, baseline]{
a[particle = \(\mu\nu\)] --[photon] b [dot],
b -- [scalar, reversed momentum'=\(\ell\), loop, min distance=2.5cm,rotate = -90] b,
};
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image: Feynman diagrams in an equation]